# Application function LabelEncoder().fit_transform in python

Tags: python

I have a theoretical question about the function LabelEncoder().fit_transform.

I am using the function / method in a classification application. It's working perfectly.

```
       #Import
       from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

       #Transform original values ​​by encoded labels
       df_data = df_data.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

However, in the documentation "sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder" have: "This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X".

I am applying this method across the dataframe. Numeric input variables (X) and categorical output variable (y). 
I thought of applying in X to transform the objective variable into the numeric type and I thought of applying in y to deal with problems of magnitude between different sources of input variables. Is this attitude correct? Is there another function that I can apply in place of LabelEncoder().fit_transform for input variables? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states [Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) should only be used to transform your lables. i.e from `'Apple', 'Orange'` to `0, 1`. If you have categorical labels then look at the [One Hot Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder). Additionally, if your input `X` have differing scales, then take a look at the [Standard Scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html?highlight=standard%20scaler#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler)